# Flink State Across multiple Transformers

Tags: java, apache-flink

How can I access a state using the same-id across multiple transformers, for example the following stores an Order object via ValueState in OrderMapper class:

```
env.addSource(source1()).keyBy(Order::getId).flatMap(new OrderMapper()).addSink(sink1());
```

Now I would like to access the same Order object via a SubOrderMapper class:

```
env.addSource(source2()).keyBy(SubOrder::getOrderId).flatMap(new SubOrderMapper()).addSink(sink2());
```

Edit: Looks like it's not possible to have state maintained across multiple operators, is there a way to have one operator accept multiple inputs, lets say 5 sources?

Comment: Can you share more info about why you want this? It's hard to propose a workable solution without understanding the actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CoProcessFunction

> To realize low-level operations on two inputs, applications can use
> CoProcessFunction or KeyedCoProcessFunction. This function is bound to
> two different inputs and gets individual calls to processElement1(...)
> and processElement2(...) for records from the two different inputs.

Also side outputs might be useful for you. [side output](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/)

Edit:
Union operator my be an option.
[Union](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/overview/#union)

Comment: I'm using CoProcess but it only takes two inout, my case requires at least 5.

Comment: no, there no 5 input function AFAIK. You can use use consecutive cocprocess functions to create a single state stream maybe.

Comment: Maybe union operator works for you?

Comment: Does Union support merging multiple Object type streams? Can u plz explain consecutive co-process option a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `EitherOfFive` class that contains one of your five different stream values (I'm assuming they are all different). See Flink's `Either` class for the one of two case.

Each input stream would use a Map function that converts the input class type to an `EitherOfFive` type.

There would be a `getKey()` method that would figure out (based on which of the five values is actually set) what key to return. And then you can have a single KeyedProcessFunction that takes as input this `EitherOfFive` type.

If the output is always the same, then you're all set. Otherwise you'll want side outputs, one per type, that feed the five different sinks.